# macOS is "Unable to Check for Updates"

Tags: macos, software-update

The hard drive on my iMac died & I had it replaced.  They installed a new drive, wiped it clean & re-installed the OS.  When I brought it home, I went through set up, pointed it at Time Machine, and viola! next memory my machine was up & running.

With one catch...

I can't get any OS updates.  It keeps saying it's unable to check for updates, make sure you connected to the Internet.

[image]

I've tried rebooting a few times to no avail.  I can also connect to websites just fine, including apple.com.

Any suggestions of what to try?

Comment: Who is *they*? Is it Apple? Or a third party?

Comment: Sorry, a local repair shop.  It was a Late 2015 iMac and Applecare no longer covered it.

Comment: There is probably your issue. iirc, unauthorized parts make apple things not work. Are you able to login with Apple ID to iCloud, iMessage, FaceTime etc.?

Comment: Are you able to see a serial number in Apple This Mac > About?

Comment: Yep, serial number is there. Able to log into iCloud, etc.

Comment: Try running `softwareupdate -l` from terminal.

Comment: safe mode 
restart command+P+R

Answer (score 2):

I had this after booting a Mac that had been off for while.  The date & time looked correct in the menubar but this fixed it for me on Monterey:

- Go into System Preferences
- Click Date & Time
- Click the Date & Time tab
- Click the Unlock icon (you'll need to enter your password)
- Uncheck the "Set date and time automatically" checkbox
- Check it again
- Click the lock icon

After that System Update started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the App Store may be having some problems today.

https://twitter.com/macrumors/status/1091369924847558658

https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

I experienced the same problem on a Mac mini (2018) running macOS 10.14.2.

Based on the comment from [JBis](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/263848/jbis), using `softwareupdate --list` was useful to confirm that an issue exists.

```
$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

On a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) I was getting similar behavior.  The difference on macOS Sierra was that the App Store Updates tab would generate a popup indicating that "An error has occurred", which also included the last line of text from the `softwareupdate` output.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your computer. That solved it for me.